# How do I change icons based on theme?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, themes

I'm creating an application who has an `.desktop` entry and my application has an icon obviously. My my logo is white and it is not appearing on Nautilus using the default theme because the nautilus background is white too.

I create two icons: one for dark backgrounds and another one for white backgrounds.

I need to set them inside my `.desktop` icon based on GNOME 3 theme (Global Dark Theme and default). How can I do it? Should I put them into different directories? But where? The documentation is not so clear to me:

- [Desktop Entry Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)
- [Icon Theme Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec)